# svn pre-commit hook to block commits without merging

Tags: svn

I was tryin to write a pre-commit hook to block developers from committing into release branch if the revision is not a merged one.
Developers are only allowed to commit a merged revision.

This is my planned action

svn:mergeinfo property will keep track of revisions merged.so in my pre-commit hook if i somehow manage to get the revision which is about to be committed.i can check it against the mergeinfo output to see if the revision is a merged one.

IN THEORY it seems easy enough.The problem is how can i get the revision.

How can i grep a revision number out of SVNLOOK command

forgive me if my question is silly.

Comment: You're trying to block accidental commits on the release branch?

Comment: No...My intention is to stop those commits in release branch which are not merged.ie,developers are only allowed to commit a merged revision.This is for me to keep track of revisions in development branches and release branches.

Comment: Then it seems like an alternate approach would be to educate the developers not to do it and control access to the release branch through permissions if that doesn’t solve the problem.  From your description it seems like I could get around your trigger by either creating a random branch, to merge into the release, or by modifying the svn:mergeinfo property before committing.

Comment: Yes u r right, one can modify svn:mergeinfo property .Damn... is there no other way to implement my idea other than educating developers??

Comment: If a developer will want to cheat, likely he will find a way. Usually it makes sense to protect from incident violations of generally accepted rules.

Answer (score 1):

If your developers aren't that educated then they probably wont realise what your svn hook is doing and if they are deliberately editing the svn:mergeinfo properties purely to commit to the release branch instead of merging then you have bigger problems.

This script checks that the commit is for the release branch.
Then it uses svnlook diff to check if there has been a property change and that svn:mergeinfo has been changed.

```
!#/bin/bash
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

#Make the release branch only accept merge commits
if svnlook changed $REPOS -t $TXN |grep -q "my-release-branch-name/" ; then
    if svnlook diff $REPOS -t $TXN |grep 'Modified: svn:mergeinfo' && svnlook diff $REPOS -t $TXN |grep 'Property changes on:'; then
        #Assume that someone hasn't gone to the trouble of making a commit look like a merge!
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Branch my-release-branch-name only accepts merge commits! " 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

Comment: this uses /bin/bash which is almost certainly wrong. You probably mean /bin/sh (this is all posix code).  If not you meant /usr/bin/env bash